# REGEX Test Always False in Shell Script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

This regular expression check in shell script always `false` despite it matches with `$LIST` values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LIST="AB,CD,EF" # Valid value and should print "VALID!"

if [[ ! "$LIST" =~ ^[A-Z]{2}(?:,[A-Z]{2})*$ ]]
then
    echo "INVALID"
else
    echo 'VALID!'
fi
```

For the `regex`, some of the invalid `$LIST` values would be `AB,CD,EF,`, `AB,CD,ef`.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex:

```
^[A-Z]{2}(?:,[A-Z]{2})*$
```

Is not POSIX regex compliant because `(?:...)` (non-capturing group) is not supported in BASH regex which is a *POSIX extended regular expression*.

Use a capturing group instead:

```
^[A-Z]{2}(,[A-Z]{2})*$
```